# Google API Apps Script Calendar Create Calendar Event Succeeds but Delete Calendar Event Fails

Tags: google-apps-script, google-api

These functions work on our test Google Corporate Calendars but fail on our production Google Corporate Calendars.  In production, the function, createCalendarEvent, works but the function, deleteCalendarEvent, fails and no error is returned.  I am using OpenID connect with the same user and same apps script.  The security access for the user has been verified to be the same on all calendars.  Here are the functions:

```
function createCalendarEvent(calendarId, startDate, endDate, eventTitle, eventDescription) {
  var cal = CalendarApp.getCalendarById(calendarId);
  var start = new Date(startDate);
  var end = new Date(endDate);
  var options = {
    description: eventDescription,
    etags: {
      "title": eventTitle,
      "start": start,
      "end": end
    }
  }
  var event = cal.createAllDayEvent(eventTitle, start, end, options);
  return event.getId();
}

function deleteCalendarEvent(calendarId, eventId)  {
  var cal = CalendarApp.getCalendarById(calendarId);
  var event = cal.getEventById(eventId);
  event.deleteEvent();
}
```

Comment: You need to debug the code.  After the code is run, click the "View" menu, and choose "Execution Transcript."  Scroll to the bottom of the log, and if there is an error, it will state what line it occurred on.  Also, read the [Trouble Shooting guide](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/support/troubleshooting)  It happens all the time, that something simple is overlooked.  You need to make sure that the `eventId` was passed in, and that an `event` was actually found.  Is there an administrator setting that can prevent event deletions?

Answer (score 0):

You could do something like this to insure that you have all parameters.

```
function deleteCalendarEvent(calendarId, eventId) {
  if(calendarId && eventId){
    CalendarApp.getCalendarById(calendarId).getEventById(eventId).deleteEvent();
  }else{
    throw('Error: in function deleteCalendarEvent. Invalid parameters.');
  }
}
```

I'd change your create function to:

```
function createCalendarEvent(calendarId, startDate, endDate, eventTitle, eventDescription) {
  var cal = CalendarApp.getCalendarById(calendarId);
  var start = new Date(startDate);
  var end = new Date(endDate);
  var options = {"description": eventDescription};
  var event = cal.createAllDayEvent(eventTitle, start, end, options);
  return event.getId();
}
```

And again you might want to wrap them with logic to insure that you have all parameters.